# Variable inputs within an IF creating a bank.

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I'm new to Python and I am currently doing some work with IF statements.
This is what I have so far...

```
print("Hello")
myName = input("What is your name?")
print("Hello " +myName)
myAge = int(input("How old are you?"))
if myAge <=18:
    myResponse = input("You must still be at school?")
    if myResponse == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES" or "Y" or "yEs" or "y":
        mySchool = input("What school do you go to?")
        print (mySchool, "that is a good school I hear")
    if myResponse == "No" or "n" or "N" or "NO":
        print("Lucky you, you have lots of free time!")
if myAge >=19:
    myResponse = input("You must have a job?")
    if myResponse == "Yes" or "yes" or "YES" or "Y" or "yEs" or "y":
        myWork = input("What do you do?")
        print (myWork, "Thats a tough job")
    if myResponse == "No" or "n" or "N" or "NO":
        print("Lucky you, you have lots of free time!")
```

I want the user to be able to answer a question with a one word answer however have various options that would be recognized by the program for example "No", "NO" and "no" or "yes", "YES" and "Yes".

I have just figured out this way of doing it seen above but is there a better way it should be done?

Bare in mind I am new to this so it is probably a silly question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Si

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please always tag your question with the name of the language you are using to help others help you better.

Comment: Please format your code with the code-format tool.

Answer (score 5):

This condition checks that myRespone is either `yes` or `"y"` and is case insensitive (meaning that `yes`, `YeS`, and others are all valid)

```
myResponse.lower() in ["yes","y"]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so would I put myResponse = input("You must still be at school?") followed by if myResponse.lower() == in ["yes", "y","YES","YeS","Y"] I'm not sure where the == goes or is it even needed (from the practice ive done on IF's so far it has always said I need to use either == < > <= >=. What is the significance of the .lower () what does that do and the in?

Comment: no ==, in already does it.

Also, the `lower` converts the string to all lower case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if myResonse.lower() == "yes":
    etc
```

Answer (score 2):

The question asks specifically for answers in the form "yes" or "no" with different capitalizations ("y" or "n" are not mentioned). With that in mind, we can do as follows, being careful to remove any extra spaces:

```
if myresponse.strip().lower() == "yes":
    # if yes, do something
```

And similarly:

```
if myresponse.strip().lower() == "no":
    # if no, do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

With string functions:

```
if myResponse.upper() == 'NO':
    # do something
```

Or:

```
if myResponse.lower() == 'no':
    #do something
```

Comment: how would you do it to accept both upper and lower case responses? for example YES, Yes, Y, y, yEs?

Comment: I would like them to have freedom to write No, no, NO how do I do this? do I write if myResponse() == 'No','no','NO'?

Comment: It doesn't matter how they wrote it, those functions will convert their input to uppercase or lowercase. Other answers already mentioned how to include 'y' or 'n'. I suggest you open an interactive shell and start learning what are the default string functions in python